# Is it safe to remove header CSS rules from inlined HTML email?

Tags: css, html-email, inline

I am using [Mailchimp's CSS inliner tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) to make all my CSS inline for a HTML email. But it doesn't remove the style rules in the header.

The same thing applies with [HTMLemail.io inliner](https://htmlemail.io/inline/). The header CSS is still there.

Is it not safe to remove CSS rules from the header after inlining them?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to remove CSS form header if INLINE css is already added.

Comment: depends if you are using media queries for a responsive email, because media queries are not inlined.

Comment: Yes there are media queries which I understand need to remain, but can all the other rules be removed?

Comment: yes you can everything that is not part of a media query as it is already inlined. i guess your email isnt allowed above a certain size :) but run a test after removing and see if it still works, email is tricky

Answer (score 1):

Media queries not work for inline elements. So if you have media-query rules they cannot be inlined. Its why `<style>` tag sometimes need to be also injected.

keep in mind that `<style>` tag is not support for all email clients, like gmail.
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/

Comment: Does that mean that any rule that falls under a media query cannot be removed, or just the media query rules themselves? Is it safe to remove everything before the `@media {...}` section

Comment: everything which is inside `@media` will not be injected as inline elements. 
Other rules probably are not used anywhere and they were not moved to inline styles, i think they can be removed safely and `@media` queries with all rules inside not.